# On input checked hide tr with certain class, but keep background color on odd rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So in this case using **bootstrap**, i would like to keep the `backgound-color` on the **odd rows**, even when hiding  a certain `tr`.

**What i want:** The grey background should in this case always be on 1st and 3rd `tr`'s if input checked or not.

This is my Code:

```js
function toggleRow() {
  if ($('#product-toggle').prop("checked")) {
    if ($('tr:has(td.status-locked)') || $('tr:has(td.product-status-whitelabel.status-locked)')) {
      $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').hide();
    }

  } else {
    $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').show();
  }
}

toggleRow();
$('#product-toggle').on('change', toggleRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<h4>If input checked hide tr with certain class(status-locked) , also keep background image on the :odd tr's</h4>

<pre>
<input type="checkbox" id="product-toggle">&nbsp;<label for="product-toggle" >click me!</label>
</pre>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
    <td class="status-locked">Entry First Line 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry Line 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry Last Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the issue? and note jQuery object will always evaluate to truthy

Comment: the issue is that if `input = checked` the `tr` with `td` class: `status-locked` is hidden but then the grey background is not on the **odd** rows as i would want it to be. its on the 1ste and second in this case(input checked).. should be on 1st and 3rd, always, checked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I have applied some jQuery for this and css.

jQuery:

```
$("table tbody").each(function() {        
    $(this).find("tr:visible:even").addClass("even").removeClass("odd");
    $(this).find("tr:visible:odd").addClass("odd").removeClass("even");
});
```

```js
function toggleRow() {
  if ($('#product-toggle').prop("checked")) {
    if ($('tr:has(td.status-locked)') || $('tr:has(td.product-status-whitelabel.status-locked)')) {
      $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').hide();
    }

  } else {
    $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').show();
  }
  $("table tbody").each(function() {        
    $(this).find("tr:visible:even").addClass("even").removeClass("odd");
    $(this).find("tr:visible:odd").addClass("odd").removeClass("even");
  });
}

toggleRow();
$('#product-toggle').on('change', toggleRow);
```

```css
#example.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
 background-color: transparent;
}
#example.table-striped > tbody > tr.even {
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<h4>If input checked hide tr with certain class(status-locked) , also keep background image on the :odd tr's</h4>

<pre>
<input type="checkbox" id="product-toggle">&nbsp;<label for="product-toggle" >click me!</label>
</pre>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
    <td class="status-locked">Entry First Line 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry Line 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry Last Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i was looking for. Someone even voted to close this ,i feel this was a valid question..anyways thanks for the help.